# How to list tickets from newest to oldest?

Tags: api, symfony, zendesk

I successfuly retrieve all tickets from my Zendesk account. But actually, there are all listed from oldest to newest (so the most recent ticket is in the 130th page). I want exactly the contrary, so the most recent in the first page. Anyone can help me ?

Answer (score 0):

I found, It's impossible using the API part dedicate to the tickets. Need to use the search function --> https://developer.zendesk.com/rest_api/docs/core/search#search